# Scriptable FTPS client able to send Keep Alive to control port?

Tags: windows, ftp, keepalive, ftps, keep-alive

We need a FTP client that satisfies the following constraints:

1. Windows
2. Command-line scriptable, so we can automate it...sorry, FileZilla (?)
3. FTPS, as it seems to perform better than SFTP
4. The ability to send KeepAlive commands to the FTPS control port during a transfer
5. No passwords sent on the command line...sorry, curl

Number 4, above, is critical: we have set KeepAlive in some other clients (e.g., CoreFTP LE) but we seem to have some routing equipment in the server environment which drops our connection when transferring a 7GB+ file. We have also set passive mode and "resume transfer" functionality seems currently broken with this secure file transport server...so we need to download the file in one go.

What FTPS clients might meet our needs?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: A modest amount. SmartFTP seems promising. WinSCP seems a possibility, but not sure if it sends KeepAlive during transfers. Core FTP does not seem to send KeepAlive during transfers. FileZilla is not scriptable. PuTTY seems to not support FTPS. WS_FTP Pro 2007 may or may not send KeepAlive...I forget. Leap FTP may send KeepAlive during transfer...and so forth, and so forth. At this point, I am attempting to identify the pool of candidates and then select one...hoping by asking I can save some time and help someone else down the road. Thanks.

Comment: After inquiring with Core FTP, it seems they will support KeepAlive to the control port beginning with forthcoming build 1791: http://www.coreftp.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=2796463

Comment: After testing WinSCP this evening, as of 5.1.7 (Build 3446), it seems to not send KeepAlive to the control port during transfers.